# html2canvas layer is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following to create an image from a div. The div has 2 layers. 1st layer is the product image and 2nd layer is where I add logos.

The problem that some of our visitors are experiencing is the code only converts the 2nd layer to an image and ignores the 1st.  Not sure how to resolve this or if I need to change the code approach?

The code works for most users, and only certain users get a blank layer 1 image.  I tried multiple browsers and it works for me, but not for them :/

**HTML**

```
<div class="canvas-left" id="layer1" style="display:inline-block; height:84%;">
 <div style="text-align:center">
  <img src="@defaultImageUrl" id="cypher-main-product-img" style="max-width:98.5%; margin-top:20px;" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="layer2" style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
```

**JS Code**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#email-btn', function () {
            var element = $("#layer1");
            var getCanvas;

            try {
                html2canvas(element, {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        getCanvas = canvas;
                        var imgbase64 = "";
                        imgbase64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                        imgbase64 = imgbase64.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

                        var _email = $("#email").val();
                        var _body = $("#message").val();
                        var _url = $("#email-from-store-url").val();
                        var _seoname = $("#seo-name").val();
                        _url = encodeURIComponent(_url);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            cache: false,
                            url: "send-email?email=" + _email + '&body=' + _body + '&url=' + _url + '&seoname=' + _seoname,
                            data: imgbase64,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (msg) {
                                alert(msg.message);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }

        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**
After changing the HTML code to make Layer 2 have the Product image as a background image, it still does the same thing.

```
    <div class="layer2" id="layer2" style="background-image:url(@defaultImageUrl); 
                                                                    background-position: center top;
                                                                    -moz-background-size: contain;
                                                                    -o-

background-size: contain;
                                                                -webkit-background-size: contain;
                                                                background-size: contain;
                                                                background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the image links were causing the issue. Some images were on www and some where non www.  Made them all standard and it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

your are missing  " useCORS: true" in your code